# Session management in client side

Tags: java, android

In my application I want to maintain session on client side, for this when user login first time I had stored current time plus session time (lets say 20 min) in preference. In BaseActivity I had written one method which checks whether current time is greater than saved time if yes then I called LoginActivity. Every other activity in application is extends from this BaseActivity.

Is this approach is efficient? Any other suggestion will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: efficient maybe, but completely useless form a security point of view. Session timeout has to happen on the server.

Comment: @Henry Ya I know from security point of view its useless. Because if I Login using other device or through web  then also 2 sessions are there but I have only choice to handle session on client side as per requirement.